# Why can't SemigroupK.combineK syntax be used for Resource[F, ?]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

Consider the following simple application:

```
import cats.effect.Resource
import cats.{Monad, SemigroupK}
import cats.syntax.semigroupk._

object ResourceSemigroupK extends App {

  //Error: value combineK is not a member of class Resource
  def combine[F[_]: SemigroupK: Monad](rsc: Resource[F, Unit], append: Resource[F, Unit]): Resource[F, Unit] = 
    rsc.combineK(append)
  
  //Works ok
  def combineExplicitly[F[_]: SemigroupK: Monad](rsc: Resource[F, Unit], append: Resource[F, Unit]): Resource[F, Unit] =
    SemigroupK[Resource[F, ?]].combineK(rsc, append)
}
```

Is there a way to apply `combineK` syntax for `Resource[F, Unit]`?

Comment: Seems to compile in 2.13.3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vFDaCiy8Ql2iRKIh9svb3Q

Comment: Maybe you are missing partial unification.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Seems to be a bug in 2.12.x versions. Thanks. Switching to 2.13.2 worked ok.

Comment: The `Resource[F, ?]` syntax is deprecated, use `Resource[F, *]` instead. The latter is supported in Dotty, so you'll have an easier time migrating to Scala 3 when the time comes. 
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7775

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt Is it available in usual kind-projector?

Comment: @SomeName yes, available

Comment: @SomeName seems to compile in 2.12.11 as well https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aJwLkvyxRqie1QjnToSGrQ maybe version of cats is outdated or try to clean compile.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Actually, it compiles fine with `*` syntax. It seems `Idea 2019.1` doesn't have support of the syntax yet.

Comment: @DmytroMitin 2.12.8 with no partial unification.